# Numpy standard deviation not working for me

Tags: python, numpy

Where I am going wrong with this `for` loop which is meant to take as input a specific corpus, sample size and number of samples and then give the average and standard deviation of expected no. of sentiment tokens?

```
def test_iterate(corpus_reader, sample_size, number_of_samples):
for i in xrange(number_of_samples):
    tokens = corpus_reader.sample_words_by_sents(sample_size)
    sents = corpus_reader.sample_sents(sample_size)
    print expected_sentiment_tokens(tokens)
    s = []
    s.append(expected_sentiment_tokens(tokens))
    s = array(s)
print "Average expected no of sentiment tokens: %s" % average(s)
print "Standard deviation of sentiment tokens: %s" % std(s)

test_iterate(rcr, 500, 3)
```

returns

```
181.166666667
186.277777778
185.5
Average expected no of sentiment tokens: 185.5
Standard deviation of sentiment tokens: 0.0
```

For some reason the average is being set to the last sample instead of averaging and standard deviating all of the samples together.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `stats` is when the standard deviation returns zero?  It seems likely that `std` is returning zero because the standard deviation of your data is zero.

Comment: please put that output in the question itself -- it's hard to read in the comments.  And you might fix the code indentation while you're at it. :^)

Comment: Are you `print` statements inside of or outside of the `for` loop? If they're outside, `std(stats)` will only evaluate the value of stats from the final iteration of the `for` loop. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: I don't understand this output at all.  It looks like your `stats`, `stats_two`, and `stats_three` values are all scalars, in which case it doesn't make any sense to take their average (which would just be itself) or their standard deviation (which would be zero), treating scalars as sequences with one element.  Maybe you meant to append them all into lists and then work with those?

Comment: as you can tell, I am a real beginner with Python. what would be the right way to code this for loop then? I can see what i've done wrong now but not too sure on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, indentation is significant in Python, so always make sure that the code in your questions looks just like the code on your screen.  Otherwise we have to guess, and if we're wrong, we can run down false trails.  Anyway, this:

```
s = []
s.append(expected_sentiment_tokens(tokens))
```

will keep making an empty list and appending one value each time inside your loop.  Doing just the expected sentiment to start with, you probably want something like

```
def test_iterate(corpus_reader, sample_size, number_of_samples):
    s = []
    for i in xrange(number_of_samples):
        tokens = corpus_reader.sample_words_by_sents(sample_size)
        exp_sent = expected_sentiment_tokens(tokens)
        print exp_sent
        s.append(exp_sent)
    print "s =", s    
    print "Average expected no of sentiment tokens: %s" % average(s)
    print "Standard deviation of sentiment tokens: %s" % std(s)

test_iterate(rcr, 500, 3)
```

[and remember, indentation matters]

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger (or even print statements) to look at the stats object that you are calling average and std on.... as DSM mentioned, it is probably std 0 (i.e. a single number or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation matters. I'm fairly certain that the code you ran is not indented in the same way as the code you've shown. Let's see the 'actual' code you ran. Also, try running smaller dummy tests like test_iterate(tcr,1,1) [if this makes sense - if not, then use the smallest case you can generate] and have it print out intermediate results. My expectation is that with stds of 0, you're working with lists of size 1. Try to find the spot where your list of data should grow and verify that it does.